# Is there an exec function that accepts a va_list argument?

Tags: c, linux, exec, glibc, variadic-functions

I am trying to implement a `spawn(const char *path, ...)` function which basically `fork`s, calls `execlp` with supplied arguments, `wait`s for the child process to exit and return the exit status.  However, there seems to be no function in the `exec` family that accepts a `va_list` argument, according to the man page `exec (3)`.  Is there such a function or is there a way to work it around?

Comment: The `execv`* functions take an array of strings.